# How to format a PHP date in .Net DataContractJsonSerializer format?

Tags: php, json, datetime

There is a requirement to send a date inside a JSON post using PHP in this following format

```
\/Date(410256000000-0800)\/
```

How do I convert a standard `dd-mm-yyyy h:i:s`  datetime like `01-01-2013 12:00:00` to that format in PHP? Just need to know what values correspond to what in that format, not really look for a `stringify` things answer.

Comment: what's that number `410256000000-0800` supposed to represent? we cannot [convert it if we don't know the format](http://php.net/date).

Comment: Yeah that's my question really that if someone knows what that format represents? According to some research it is  .Net DataContractJsonSerializer format

Comment: it must be `u` to be that big. just a guess did you try `u`?

Comment: I _think_ that format might be the unix timestamp value (in milliseconds) plus the timezone offset that should be used when _displaying_ the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', '01-01-2013 12:00:00');

$requiredJsonFormat = sprintf(
    '\/Date(%s%s)\/',
    $dateTime->format('U') * 1000,
    $dateTime->format('O')
);

echo $requiredJsonFormat; // prints '\/Date(1357038000000+0100)\/'
```

I leave it up to you to find what the formats `U` and `O` do from http://php.net/date.

An alternative would be to use PHP's [DOTNET](http://php.net/dotnet) API and use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class directly from PHP. However, you'd need .NET installed on the server and using PHP's DOTNET API is rather arcane.

The more interesting part is why you need this format at all. This is explained in a blogpost at http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/18/dates-and-json.aspx

> But because of a strange oversight in the EcmaScript specs, there is no standard way of describing dates in JSON. […] Our current approach is using a small loophole in the JSON specs. In a JSON string literal, you may (or may not) escape some characters. Among those characters, weirdly enough, there is the slash character ('/'). […] The new format is "/Date(1198908717056)/" where the number is again the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970 UTC […] The point is that this disambiguates a date literal from a string that looks like the same date literal, while remaining pure JSON that will be parsed by any standard JSON parser. Of course, a parser that doesn't know about this convention will just see a string, but parsers that do will be able to parse those as dates without a risk for false positives

Comment: Thanks Gordon for taking time to research on this. So very appreciated that is. Your answer is very helpful

Answer (score 2):

We created a package for this: https://github.com/webapix/dot-net-json-date-formatter

It uses a similar approach than the previous answer, tested on PHP versions >= 5.6.

```
use DateTime;
use DateTimeZone;
use Webapix\DotNetJsonDate\Date;

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd-m-Y H:i:s',
    '01-01-2013 12:00:00',
    new DateTimeZone('+0000')
);

Date::toJsonDate($date); // returns '/Date(1357041600000+0000)/'
```